# File system for remote connection with 2FA

Tags: ssh, filesystems

recently the cluster I have been using installed two-factor authentication (2FA) with OTP (one-time pad). Is there a possibility to use file viewers (like Forklift) on MacOs with the 2FA or mount the remote disc locally to easy access all files? (Using scp from terminal is very bothersome with an immense number of files)

Thanks for any help!